# É possível saber em qual site meu link foi clicado?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um link do meu site em alguns outros sites e gostaria de saber se é possível saber em qual site ele foi clicado, me informando a url do site por exemplo. E se for possível, como faço isso? qual linguagem? se é possível com php?
Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Por enquanto sim - se o usuário clicar num link que leve para a sua página, com algumas restrições, a URL da página anterior é enviada para seu servidor no cabeçalho HTTP.

E nesse caso, o conteúdo desse cabeçalho vai estar disponível dentro do código PHP como `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Caso a tecnologia do lado do servidor não seja PHP, ou você esteja manipulando o HTTP "bruto", o nome do cabeçalho é simplesmente `referer` (a palavra correta em Inglês seria `referrer`, mas isso vem dos primórdios da web, e fizeram errado mesmo).

A documentação do cabeçalho pode ser vista aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer . Em particular: se a página anterior fosse com o protocolo `file://` ou `data`, o referrer não é passado. Se a página anterior fosse `http` e a sua for `https` o referrer não é passado também.

Por quê "por enquanto"? Por que os produtores de navegadores estão cientes que esse tipo de informação da margem a muitas situações de quebra de privacidade - e pode ser que nos próximos meses aumentem bem as restrições para o envio desse cabeçalho nos principais navegadores.

Uma solução a longo prazo, e mais correta, é gerar links personalizados para cada site parceiro - com um trecho de dados que corresponda a um objeto na sua base de dados: dessa forma você sempre vai saber qual link foi usado e pode associar quanta informação quiser a cada link.

Quanto a saber de qual site a navegação veio em código front-end, no Javascript:você pode usar  `document.referrer`, que é preenchido com a mesma informação. Apesar dos navegadores terem a propriedade `document.history` e o objeto `History`, esses objetos não revelam as URLs do history a código não privilegiado (qualquer código rodando em uma página web). É possível usar esses objetos para enviar o usuário de volta "ao lugar de onde ele veio", usando-se o método `back()` - mas a única forma do código Javascript saber de onde veio a navegação é se a aplicação do lado do servidor pegar o conteúdo do cabeçalho `referer` e coloca-lo no template da página (ou servi-lo como web-service).

Não verifiquei exemplos ou documentação, mas eu suponho que código Javascript escrito em extensões dos navegadores seja "privilegiado" e possa ter acesso explícito ao conteúdo do `document.history`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não vou saber postar uma solução melhor que as citadas abaixo, mas numa hospedagem que eu tenho pra saber de onde vem os links em cada lugar que postei eu coloquei na própria URL, isso por que estão em vários lugares links de acesso direto a algumas páginas.
No site1:

`http://meusite.com/meudiretorio/?get=meulink&ref=http://www.algumblog.com`

No site2:

`http://meusite.com/meudiretorio/?get=meulink&ref=http://www.algumforum.com.br`

Daí o PHP que vai capturar a informação:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
   $ref =  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}else{
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
      $ref = $_GET['ref'];
   }else{
      $ref = "Sem referencia!";
   }
}
/* Após verificação da referencia */
echo $ref;
?>
```

A variável GLOBAL $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] deve ser considerada primeiro por que o link com a referência pode ter sido copiado por outra pessoa e repostada em outro site.

Se achar estranho ou "feio", pode colocar a referencia em BASE64:

No site1:

`http://meusite.com/meudiretorio/?get=meulink&ref=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hbGd1bWJsb2cuY29t`

No site2:

`http://meusite.com/meudiretorio/?get=meulink&ref=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hbGd1bWZvcnVtLmNvbS5icg==`

Daí lembre de decodificar na linha caso usar o método GET:

```
$ref = base64_decode($_GET['ref']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Vincule seu site com uma conta Google Analytics, insira no código fonte o pedaço de código onde seu site passará a ser monitorado pelo mesmo, e após 24hs você terá acesso aos recursos para saber as fontes de onde vieram os cliques, de quais sites e muito mais informações.

O Google Analytics é uma ferramenta muito útil para profissionais de marketing. Neste post, vamos mostrar como uma análise correta dos dados faz toda a diferença!
O Google Analytics é um dos principais parceiros de qualquer profissional de marketing e isso não é segredo para ninguém. Porém saber utilizar essa ferramenta de maneira estratégica, e não só como fonte de dados, exige muito mais conhecimento.

Mais do que um conjunto de números e estatísticas, um bom analista deve saber entender de onde está vindo o tráfego do site, como os usuários estão se comportando e qual é o fluxo de visitas mais comum dentro das páginas, por exemplo.

Porém, como sabemos, o Google Analytics não é uma ferramenta tão simples assim. É muito comum ter dúvidas no momento de entender melhor as métricas e resultados.

Por exemplo, você sabe o que significa o Tráfego Direto do seu blog? Esta é uma das dúvidas mais frequentes que vemos aqui na Rock Content e, por isso, decidimos produzir este conteúdo para tirar essa dúvida de uma vez por todas. Vamos lá?

O que é o Tráfego Direto?
Por definição do próprio Google Analytics (GA), uma sessão direta é aquele tráfego que não tem uma origem muito bem definida.

Ou seja, nem sempre a Analytics consegue identificar qual é a origem real do tráfego do seu site, classificando como Tráfego Direto o que era realmente tráfego de redes sociais ou de anúncios, por exemplo.

Quando acontece uma sessão Direta?
Como padrão, algumas das principais fontes de Tráfego Direto são quando algum usuário digita o domínio do seu site (www.marketingdeconteudo.com, por exemplo) diretamente no navegador ou até mesmo já tinha marcado o seu site na sessão de favoritos do navegador para acessar facilmente.

Entretanto, como já dissemos anteriormente, o Tráfego Direto também engloba uma quantidade de visitas mais ampla, que vai além dessas duas situações mostradas.

Basicamente, as sessões diretas ocorrem a qualquer momento em que o Google Analytics não conseguir identificar outra fonte de tráfego. Algumas dessas situações são:

Cliques em links de emails (dependendo do provedor de email do usuário);
Cliques em links em Microsoft Office ou documentos PDF;
Acessos ao site provenientes de links encurtados (dependendo do encurtador de link utilizado);
Cliques em links de aplicativos mobile de redes sociais, como Facebook e Twitter. Aplicativos mobile geralmente não passam informações corretas de origem;
Acesso a um site “não-seguro” (protocolo http), vindo de um site “seguro” (protocolo https), já que o site seguro não passa a informação de origem de tráfego para o site não-seguro. Por exemplo, se alguém clica em um link na página https://empresa1.com para ir para uma página http://empresa2.com, o GA da empresa 2 vai mostrar essa sessão como Tráfego Direto;
Campanhas em redes sociais, email marketing, anúncios pagos, ou qualquer outra forma de linkagem em que a URL não está com os parâmetros de origem definidos corretamente podem ser lidos como Tráfego Direto;
Experimento sobre o Tráfego Direto
Um experimento interessante foi feito pela empresa Groupon para entender qual era o percentual de sessões que eram lidar como Tráfego Direto mas, na verdade, eram provenientes de Tráfego Orgânico.

Foi feito um teste em que os responsáveis pelo site utilizaram o Google Search Console para “desindexar” o site do Google por algumas horas, ou seja, o domínio não apareceria quando os usuários fizessem alguma busca, mesmo quando as páginas do site já estivesse indexando nas primeiras posições.

A conclusão do experimento foi de que cerca de 60% do Tráfego que o GA lê como Direto é, na verdade, Tráfego Orgânico que não foi interpretado corretamente pelo Analytics — tendo como base apenas páginas de URLs longas.

Este é um teste muito ousado e extremo, por isso, não recomendamos que você faça isso no seu site. Porém, podemos utilizar esse experimento como uma base de comparação.

Para saber mais sobre o experimento e as metodologias utilizadas, leia aqui o relato completo de Gene McKenna, Diretor de Produto da Groupon.

Como consertar a leitura do seu Tráfego Direto
Como você já pode perceber até agora, as origens exatas do Tráfego Direto ainda são um mistério para quem trabalha com marketing. Porém, existem algumas formas de minimizar esses erros de leitura do GA.

Confira algumas delas a seguir!

Utilize parâmetros identificadores nas URLs de suas campanhas
Para campanhas específicas, como disparo de emails ou anúncios em redes sociais, por exemplo, você pode adicionar parâmetros nas URLs de destino do seu site para garantir que o Analytics leia aquele tráfego com as fontes de origem corretamente.

O jeito mais fácil de construir uma URL com parâmetros corretamente é utilizando o Campain URL Builder, em que você pode selecionar as informações como quer que sejam lidas pelo GA.

Fique atento a mudanças repentinas nas fontes de tráfego do seu site
Profissionais de marketing já estão acostumados a acompanhar o relatório de canais de aquisição de tráfego (no relatório de Aquisição > Todo o tráfego > Canais).

Então uma das melhores formas de entender quando o seu GA está lendo o Tráfego Direto de maneira indevida é procurando por mudanças drásticas em todos os canais — e não só no Tráfego Direto.

Sabemos que  o Analytics pode interpretar algumas sessões como “Tráfego Direto” indevidamente.

Se você reparar que o tráfego de Referências (Referral) ou Orgânico, por exemplo, tiverem mudanças significativas ao mesmo tempo em que o Tráfego Direto, pode ser que aconteceu alguma mudança na leitura das visitas.

Fonte: https://marketingdeconteudo.com/trafego-direto-no-google-analytics/